# How do I generate a league table using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel file that gives the 1st, 2nd and 3rd place winners of various quizzes I've run. The data is in the following format:

| Date | 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Sept | Bob | Alice | Chris |
| 1st Oct | Alice | Tom | Bob |

I want to turn this results table into a league table, where 1st place gets 3 points, second gets 2 points and 3rd gets 1 point. I'd like it to automatically update as more result rows are added each week. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding all the distinct names in another column. You'll then create a COUNTIFS formula, one that looks up that name in your results table.

The formula will count the number of times the person has won first place and multiply by 3, PLUS, count the times they won 2nd place and multiply by 2, PLUS count the third place finishes.

Formula for cell G2:

```
    =(COUNTIFS(B:B,F2)*3)+(COUNTIFS(C:C,F2)*2)+(COUNTIFS(D:D,F2))
```

Drag it down, done. You can then sort columns F and G by G descending for your leaderboard.

[image]